# problems with labels in ggplot2 within shiny context

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, geom-text

I have some problems with the labels position and their appearance in my plot below.

1) I would like to keep the ylim as it is (ylim(0,100)) but extend the y bar such that the labels are readable.

2)Also, the position of the labels does not seem to be at exactly the middle of bars. I tried  different widths but it did fix the issue.

3)How can I define three cbbPalette and add additional colors, for example, 80 additional colors, without specifying the colors one by one? In other words, I would like to keep the three below colors and several other but I would like to specify only three of them. I do not care the rest colors.

[image]

```
  cbbPalette <- c("#B61E2E", "#0072B2", "#56B4E9")

scale_fill_manual(values=cbbPalette)+
      geom_text(
        aes(label = Percentage2),
        vjust = 0,
        colour = "black", 
        position = position_dodge(width=0.9),
        fontface = "bold",
        size=4,
         angle = 90,
        hjust = 0
      ) +ylim(0,100)+
```

Comment: For #1, ggplot2 will plot to the size of the plot window. when you save you can specify height and width to extend the y bar - for example `ggsave(file="MyPlot.png", width=4, height=4, dpi=300)`

Comment: Thanks. The problem is the case within shiny context so appearance of the labels matters before saving the plot.

Comment: Q1. Extend the y bar? What do you mean? Try increasing the max ylim a little to, say 115.  For Q2, try `vjust=0.5`. For Q3, I don't understand.  And you should provide a sample dataset.